# ImportError: No module named gi.repository

Tags: python, repository, gobject, nautilus

I'm trying to launch python script on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject
```

It doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject
   ImportError: No module named gi.repository
```

I installed `python-gobject-dev`, `python-gobject`, `python-nautilus`, but it didn't help.
Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 10):

Try to fix it by installing [PyGObject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html):

```
# With Apt on Ubuntu:
$ sudo apt install python3-gi

# With Yum on CentOS / RHEL:
$ sudo yum install python36-gobject.x86_64 

# Or directly with Pip:
$ pip3 install PyGObject
```

Answer (score 4):

@hob's answer for Anaconda didn't work for me, but `conda install -c conda-forge pygobject` did.

Comment: You're right. Doesn't look like conda supports `-c auto` anymore  `-c conda-forge` is the right channel, if you don't already have it set up in your conda config.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-gobject
```

Fixed it for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

[Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) usually has python package binaries that will work with your platform (Mac or older Ubuntu). According to @Abhijit you need `pygobject`. It works a lot like `pip`:

```
conda install -c auto pygobject
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install pygobject, pygobject3(3 comes from the gtk version, not python).

If you're on Mac:

- `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null` Install the latest version of homebrew
- `brew install pygobject` Install pyobject
- `brew install pygobject3` Install pyobject3
- `mkdir -p /Users/abhijit/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` Check and build the sitepath directory if it doesn't exist
- `echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/abhijit/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth` Create a shortcut in your python Site-packages to your homebrew path

Answer (score 1):

10.04?  That's pre-GNOME 3, so the preferred Python bindings were based on PyGTK, not PyGObject.  You need to either use the (obsolete) PyGTK bindings or upgrade to a newer OS.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS):

`sudo apt reinstall python3-gi`

Answer (score 0):

very simple.
open /usr/bin/gnome-terminal,you can see the interpreter is python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Change the path of the interpreter to python3.5:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
```

Fixed it for me on Ubuntu 16.04.